# laravel userstamps without disturbing the database seeding

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding, laravel-events

Is there any way to automate the filling of a `created_by` column without the use of observers, but keeping my controllers clean? I don't want to use observers because when I try to seed my database, errors happen.

The way I'm doing now:

```php
class ClientObserver
{
    public function creating(Client $client)
    {
        $client->author()->associate(auth()->user());
    }
}
```

and it works for creating clients through the app when I register into a service provider's boot, but when I use artisan to seed the database with that factory:

```php
$factory->define(Client::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->company,
        'description' => $faker->paragraph,
        'address' => $faker->address,
        'created_by' => User::all()->random()->id,
    ];
});
```

I get this error:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: clients.created_by
```

because the "creating" event is triggered and the observer acts. Is there at least some way to stop the observer from taking action?

Any help will be welcome. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the seeder, set and unset a config value before and after the factory.

```php
// DatabaseSeeder.php
public function run()
{
    config()->set('seeding', true);

    factory(App\Client::class, 50)->create();

    config()->set('seeding', false);
}
```

You can avoid having an `Observer` by overriding the boot method of your model.  Check for the config value and set the user as required.

```php
// Client.php
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function($client) {
        if (config()->get('seeding') === true)
            auth()->setUser(User::inRandomOrder()->first());
        $client->author()->associate(auth()->user());
    });
}
```

Comment: It worked, tnks! The only thing I want to point out: `User::random()` is undefined. `User::all()->random()` and `User::inRandomOrder()->first()` did the trick (think the last is fast, but idk).

Comment: yes, you're correct.  the dangers of coding in the browser... think I might have quoted an older Laravel method, but you got the idea.  I updated the code with your suggestion.  anyways glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can `Login` before seeding

```php
    // DatabaseSeeder.php
    public function run()
    {
        Auth::loginUsingId(1);
    
        factory(App\Client::class, 50)->create();
    
    }
```